# not getting conflicts from git rebase as expected

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have two branches:

- `dev`: A-B-C
- `feature`: A-Z

  When I checkout `feature` and do `git rebase dev` I get:
  `First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...`
  `Fast-forwarded feature to dev`
  But my feature branch looks like A-Z-B-C instead of A-B-C-Z; `dev` and `feature` are the same because they share the same files and they are now in the same state (C) whereas I was expecting to get conflicts.

Can somebody help?

Comment: The output you showed implies that `dev` really is `A-Z-B-C` already and therefore there are no commits on `feature` that are not already on `dev`. You might consider running `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` before starting the rebase.

Comment: thanks, that helped much